# Why did I need to switch several appliances in order to power my electric stove?

Tags: electrical

This is a bit more theoretical but I am confused as to how this may have happened. I own an electric stove that is plugged into one of those large 240V sockets on the wall. Yesterday when I switched on the oven the appliance completely shut off but did not trip the circuit breaker so no other devices around my kitchen switched off. In order to turn it on again I tried to reset the circuit breaker but that didn't work. Then someone suggested that I power off some of my AC's which consume about half a KW, I did and after I reset the circuit breaker once again sure enough, the stove turned on. Needless to say I was completely dumbfounded.

So question 1) why would only the stove itself switch off without tripping the circuit breaker? It is simply connected to the socket without any sort of surge protector. 2) Most importantly why would I need to unplug some of the other appliances in my house just to turn the stove on? this is what confused me the most. I thought things just scaled, I am sure the power grid can carry much bigger loads than whatever my house was consuming.

Comment: I am pretty sure the CB was tripped. Perhaps the switch went half way, as some of these thing do..

Comment: But if the CB was tripped, it would have switched off other appliances in my kitchen (microwave), which it didn't...

Comment: It shouldn't have switched any other appliance. The stove should be on its own dedicated circuit.

Comment: Assuming we're talking about the US.

Comment: @ThePhoton yes this is the US. I will verify if its on its own CB.

Comment: It's possible that over time the breaker has been hot and caused damage to the buss inside the breaker box.  In this case the act of resetting the second time caused it to "wiggle" into a position where it works.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you are in the United States for this answer. A stove is normally on a dedicated circuit which means it alone is the only load wired to a particular circuit breaker. This means nothing else would have been affected if your stove's breaker tripped. The breaker for your stove will be larger than a normal 120V breaker in your panel so you would have had to reset this if the breaker indeed tripped. If your stove was still on, resetting the breaker may have been difficult; the switch may have been difficult or impossible to switch to the "ON" position.

I am assuming you unknowingly reset the breaker when you were switching things in your breaker panel. If you are certain you didn't, then you may have never actually tripped a breaker and have some other electrical problem.